# check_password() in django always returning false

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am making a custom reset password module. I am checking the old password with django auth User model. But check_password is always returning false. Please help if there is mistake in my logic.

views.py

```
def user_pass_change(request):
    pass_old = request.POST.get('old_pass')
    hash_pass_new = make_password(request.POST.get('new_pass'))
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    if user:
        check = check_password(user.password,pass_old)

        if check:
            User.objects.filter(username=username).update(password=hash_pass_new)
            messages.success(request, 'Password changed !')
            return redirect('/login')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Wrong old password')
            return redirect('/login')
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'Invalid Username !')
        return redirect('/login')
```

I have tried including these hashers in setting.py

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you defining/importing `check_password()`?  As far as I know, that function is a member of the `User` model, and only takes one argument like so: `user.check_password(pass_old)`, but here you're using it as a standalone function that takes _two_ arguments.

Comment: Does this solve the problem?  ```user.check_password(old_pass)```

Answer (score 2):

`user.password` is a HASH of the password and not the actual password. `check_password` expects a raw string. [[Django Docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password)

To check if the current password is same as the `pass_old` you can do this:

```
check = user.check_password(pass_old) # user is the User object
```